# Mouse out stop sound

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a piano menu and I would like to be able to mouse out and back on straight away to replay the sound however I am getting a delay to as when I can play the key again.

So far using Stackoverflow, I have come up with the following whereas I can play key notes on hover however it doesn't yet feel too much like a piano.

### A & B KEYS HAVE SOUND

```js
$(function(){
 var Key_A     = $('.KEY_A');
 var Key_B     = $('.KEY_B');
 
 var A_Audio = Key_A.find('audio')[0];
 var B_Audio = Key_B.find('audio')[0];

 Key_A.hover(function(){
  A_Audio.play();
 }, function(){
    A_Audio.stop();
 });
 
 Key_B.hover(function(){
  B_Audio.play();
 }, function(){
    B_Audio.stop();
 });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

body {background-color:#222}
p {margin:0 0 1.5em}

*,
*:before,
*:after {box-sizing:border-box}

/*
Pure CSS3 Vertical Piano Menu by Taufik Nurrohman (http://gplus.to/tovic)
Licence: Attribution
*/

#nav-piano {
  display:block;
  background-color:#222;
  background-image:linear-gradient(60deg,#111,#333,#111,#3c3c3c,#333 70%);
  width:300px;
  padding:0 15px 40px 0;
  border-right:1px solid #111;
  border-bottom:1px solid #111;
  border-radius:0 0 7px 0;
  box-shadow:2px 0 0 #666,3px 0 0 #555,4px 0 0 #444,6px 0 6px black,inset -1px 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5),inset -4px 0 5px black,-5px 0 10px black,-2px 10px 14px black;;
  float:left;
  margin-top:-10px;
  margin-bottom:200px;
}

#nav-piano ul,
#nav-piano li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
}

#nav-piano ul {box-shadow:0 2px 5px black}

#nav-piano a,
#nav-piano .tut {
  display:block;
  height:40px;
  padding:0 18px 0 0;
  background-color:#fafafa;
  background-image:linear-gradient(-30deg,#f5f5f5,white);
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow:inset 1px 0 0 white,inset -1px 0 0 white,inset 0 0 0 1px white,4px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  border-radius:0 3px 3px 0;
  text-align:right;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#666;
  text-shadow:0 1px 0 white;
  font:italic normal 14px/37px Georgia,"URW Bookman L",Serif;
  outline:none;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#nav-piano a:focus,
#nav-piano a:active {outline:none}

#nav-piano .black-tut a,
#nav-piano .black-tut .tut {
  width:58%;
  z-index:2;
  background-color:#111;
  background-image:linear-gradient(-20deg,#333,black,#333);
  height:26px;
  line-height:24px;
  font-size:11px;
  text-shadow:0 -1px 0 black;
  color:#555;
  margin-top:-13px;
  margin-bottom:-13px;
  border-width:2px 7px 2px 1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#666 #222 #111 #555;
  box-shadow:inset -1px 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.4),2px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

#nav-piano a:active {
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
  margin-right:1px;
  box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
#nav-piano .black-tut a:active {
  border-right-width:2px;
  left:-2px;
  box-shadow:inset -1px 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.4),1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.8),0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4),1px 0 0 black;
}

#nav-piano li ul {
  position:absolute;
  top:-10px;
  left:100%;
  margin-left:-10px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#ffa;
  padding:10px 0;
  z-index:999;
  overflow:hidden;
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:all .2s ease-out;
}

#nav-piano li ul a,
#nav-piano li ul a:active {
  background:none;
  border:none;
  border-radius:0;
  box-shadow:none;
  height:24px;
  line-height:24px;
  color:#8b8b55;
  text-shadow:none;
  margin-right:0;
}

/* Depth Shadow */
#nav-piano > ul > li > a:active:before,
#nav-piano > ul > li > a:active:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  height:15px;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  transform:rotate(1deg) translateY(-15px);
}

#nav-piano > ul > li > a:active:after {
  top:auto;
  bottom:0;
  transform:rotate(-1deg) translateY(14px);
}

#nav-piano li ul a:hover {background-color:#fc6}

#nav-piano li:hover ul {
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  margin-left:-5px;
}

/* Content area */
#content {
  display:block;
  margin-left:350px;
  padding:30px 40px 0 0;
  font:normal normal 13px/1.4 Georgia,"URW Bookman L",Serif;
  color:#777;
  text-shadow:0 1px 1px black;
  max-width:700px;
}

#content h2 {
  font:italic normal 300%/normal "Bodoni MT",Didot,"Didot LT STD","Hoefler Text",Garamond,"Times New Roman",Times,Serif;
  color:#584D46;
  margin:0 0 .4em;
}

#content h2:before {
  content:"*";
  font-style:normal;
}

#content a {
  color:#666;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#content a:hover {color:#999}

#content footer {
  border-top:1px dashed #333;
  padding-top:1.5em;
  margin-top:2em;
  font-size:11px;
  font-style:italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav-piano">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="black-tut"><a href="#">Alternate Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="black-tut"><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
    <li class="black-tut"><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li class="black-tut"><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li><span class="tut">D</span></li>
    <li class="black-tut"><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li><span class="tut">C</span></li>
    <li>
        <span class="tut KEY_B">
            B
            <audio src="http://rafflebananza.com/Admin/Desktop/piano-b.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="black-tut"><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li>
        <span class="tut KEY_A">
         A
            <audio src="http://rafflebananza.com/Admin/Desktop/piano-a.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="black-tut"><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li class="black-tut"><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li><span class="tut"></span></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- Other stuff -->
<section id="content">
  <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p><p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
  <footer>Posted by <a href="http://gplus.to/tovic">Taufik Nurrohman</a></footer>
</section>
```

Comment: I would warmly recommend using [Sound Manager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) - it is great! Please look at [this example](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/mpc/).

Comment: @skobaljic Plus 1 - That is really cool but extremely distracting! haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are calling "audio.stop()" when there is no such method. You should instead pause and reset the clip before trying to play it again as shown below.

Reference: [MDN - Media Element Properties and Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Methods)

**To view and try the complete code, click "Show code snippet" and then "Run code snippet".**

```
  Key_A.hover(function() {
    A_Audio.pause();
    A_Audio.currentTime = 0;
    A_Audio.play();
  }); 

  Key_B.hover(function() {
    B_Audio.pause();
    B_Audio.currentTime = 0;
    B_Audio.play();
  });
```

```js
$(function(){
 var Key_A     = $('.KEY_A');
 var Key_B     = $('.KEY_B');
 
 var A_Audio = Key_A.find('audio')[0];
 var B_Audio = Key_B.find('audio')[0];

  Key_A.hover(function() {
    A_Audio.pause();
    A_Audio.currentTime = 0;
    A_Audio.play();
  }); 
              
  Key_B.hover(function() {
    B_Audio.pause();
    B_Audio.currentTime = 0;
    B_Audio.play();
  });
  
  
  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

body {background-color:#222}
p {margin:0 0 1.5em}

*,
*:before,
*:after {box-sizing:border-box}

/*
Pure CSS3 Vertical Piano Menu by Taufik Nurrohman (http://gplus.to/tovic)
Licence: Attribution
*/

#nav-piano {
  display:block;
  background-color:#222;
  background-image:linear-gradient(60deg,#111,#333,#111,#3c3c3c,#333 70%);
  width:300px;
  padding:0 15px 40px 0;
  border-right:1px solid #111;
  border-bottom:1px solid #111;
  border-radius:0 0 7px 0;
  box-shadow:2px 0 0 #666,3px 0 0 #555,4px 0 0 #444,6px 0 6px black,inset -1px 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5),inset -4px 0 5px black,-5px 0 10px black,-2px 10px 14px black;;
  float:left;
  margin-top:-10px;
  margin-bottom:200px;
}

#nav-piano ul,
#nav-piano li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
}

#nav-piano ul {box-shadow:0 2px 5px black}

#nav-piano a,
#nav-piano .tut {
  display:block;
  height:40px;
  padding:0 18px 0 0;
  background-color:#fafafa;
  background-image:linear-gradient(-30deg,#f5f5f5,white);
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow:inset 1px 0 0 white,inset -1px 0 0 white,inset 0 0 0 1px white,4px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  border-radius:0 3px 3px 0;
  text-align:right;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#666;
  text-shadow:0 1px 0 white;
  font:italic normal 14px/37px Georgia,"URW Bookman L",Serif;
  outline:none;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#nav-piano a:focus,
#nav-piano a:active {outline:none}

#nav-piano .black-tut a,
#nav-piano .black-tut .tut {
  width:58%;
  z-index:2;
  background-color:#111;
  background-image:linear-gradient(-20deg,#333,black,#333);
  height:26px;
  line-height:24px;
  font-size:11px;
  text-shadow:0 -1px 0 black;
  color:#555;
  margin-top:-13px;
  margin-bottom:-13px;
  border-width:2px 7px 2px 1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#666 #222 #111 #555;
  box-shadow:inset -1px 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.4),2px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

#nav-piano a:active {
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
  margin-right:1px;
  box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
#nav-piano .black-tut a:active {
  border-right-width:2px;
  left:-2px;
  box-shadow:inset -1px 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.4),1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.8),0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4),1px 0 0 black;
}

#nav-piano li ul {
  position:absolute;
  top:-10px;
  left:100%;
  margin-left:-10px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#ffa;
  padding:10px 0;
  z-index:999;
  overflow:hidden;
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:all .2s ease-out;
}

#nav-piano li ul a,
#nav-piano li ul a:active {
  background:none;
  border:none;
  border-radius:0;
  box-shadow:none;
  height:24px;
  line-height:24px;
  color:#8b8b55;
  text-shadow:none;
  margin-right:0;
}

/* Depth Shadow */
#nav-piano > ul > li > a:active:before,
#nav-piano > ul > li > a:active:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  height:15px;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  transform:rotate(1deg) translateY(-15px);
}

#nav-piano > ul > li > a:active:after {
  top:auto;
  bottom:0;
  transform:rotate(-1deg) translateY(14px);
}

#nav-piano li ul a:hover {background-color:#fc6}

#nav-piano li:hover ul {
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  margin-left:-5px;
}

/* Content area */
#content {
  display:block;
  margin-left:350px;
  padding:30px 40px 0 0;
  font:normal normal 13px/1.4 Georgia,"URW Bookman L",Serif;
  color:#777;
  text-shadow:0 1px 1px black;
  max-width:700px;
}

#content h2 {
  font:italic normal 300%/normal "Bodoni MT",Didot,"Didot LT STD","Hoefler Text",Garamond,"Times New Roman",Times,Serif;
  color:#584D46;
  margin:0 0 .4em;
}

#content h2:before {
  content:"*";
  font-style:normal;
}

#content a {
  color:#666;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#content a:hover {color:#999}

#content footer {
  border-top:1px dashed #333;
  padding-top:1.5em;
  margin-top:2em;
  font-size:11px;
  font-style:italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav-piano">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="black-tut"><a href="#">Alternate Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="black-tut"><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
    <li class="black-tut"><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li class="black-tut"><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li><span class="tut">D</span></li>
    <li class="black-tut"><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li><span class="tut">C</span></li>
    <li>
        <span class="tut KEY_B">
            B
            <audio src="http://rafflebananza.com/Admin/Desktop/piano-b.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="black-tut"><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li>
        <span class="tut KEY_A">
         A
            <audio src="http://rafflebananza.com/Admin/Desktop/piano-a.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="black-tut"><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li class="black-tut"><span class="tut"></span></li>
    <li><span class="tut"></span></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- Other stuff -->
<section id="content">
  <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p><p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
  <footer>Posted by <a href="http://gplus.to/tovic">Taufik Nurrohman</a></footer>
</section>
```

Comment: This partly does the job +1 However this plays the sound on mouse out as well as on mouse over. Probably a simple fix, not had chance to look through how you have achieved this. Will look in a moment. Thank you :)

Comment: Actually, I'm not certain how to modify to achieve.

Comment: Simples! Change `.hover()` to `.mouseover` and it works perfectly!